# INSERT SELECT в ту же таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Приветствую!
Есть задача: вставить в таблицу данные, если два поля в этой таблице не принадлежат условиям(в таблице есть дата прибытия и выезда и надо чтобы новая запись не могла пересечься с предыдущей по датам)

Я начал с такого кода:

```
INSERT INTO `occupation`(`id`, `arrival`, `departure`, `clientid`)  SELECT 3, '2017-12-4', '2017-12-14', 1 FROM `occupation` WHERE 1
```

Не понимаю почему, но даже в пустую таблицу он почему-то ничего не добавляет.

В будущем расширил до:

```
INSERT INTO `occupation`(`id`, `arrival`, `departure`, `clientid`) SELECT ?, ?, ?, ? FROM `occupation` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `occupation` WHERE `arrival` >= ? AND `departure` <= ?  AND `id` = ?)
```

Но и этот код, конечно не работает(тем более его надо дополнять, учитывая еще 2 условия с датами, когда одна из дат попадает в промежуток, а вторя лежит вне него).

P.S. Может где-то криво написал, прошу прощения за это... Всем спасибо!

Comment: Когда надо обеспечить уникальность в таблице -- на неё накладывают ограничение, уникальный индекс UNIQUE KEY. В этом случае нет нужды писать какой-то код: за вас проверку уникальности сделаем сам mysql-сервер, причём наиболее гарантированным и консистентным образом.

Comment: Тут надо не уникальное значение, а смысл уникаольности заключается в промежутке дат: надо чтобы весь промежуток был уникальным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать

```
INSERT INTO `occupation` (`id`, `arrival`, `departure`, `clientid`) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT $id, $arrival, $departure, $clientid) as tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM `occupation` WHERE `id` = $id AND 
           ($arrival BETWEEN `arrival` AND `departure` OR
            $departure BETWEEN `arrival` AND `departure`)
)
```

Comment: Работает! Такой запрос выполняется вручную, но почему-то не хочет выполняться в php(использую mysqli stmt). Ошибка выглядит так: Duplicate column name '?'

Comment: Странно, что при запуске руками не происходит ошибки ( Может вот это оно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343164/duplicate-column-name-error-in-mysql-query

Comment: Не получилось.. сейчас запрос выглядит так: `INSERT INTO occupation(id, arrival, departure, clientid)
       SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?) AS tmp
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM occupation WHERE occupation.id=? AND (? BETWEEN occupation.arrival AND occupation.departure OR ? BETWEEN occupation.arrival AND occupation.departure)
       );` Может что-то не так с BETWEEN?

Comment: Вопрос - имя поля? Тогда разбирайтесь с кавычками в запросе, скорее всего

Comment: Вопрос может оказаться именем поля только в BETWEEN я так понимаю

Comment: Скорее с постановкой параметров. Я не пользовался этой библиотекой. Посмотреть сгенеренный запрос можно?

Comment: `INSERT INTO occupation(id, arrival, departure, clientid) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 3, '2017-12-1', '2017-12-4', 1) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM occupation WHERE id=3 AND ('2017-12-1' BETWEEN arrival AND departure OR '2017-12-4' BETWEEN arrival AND departure) );`. Короче весь прикол что в случае с BETWEEN первый параметр должен вроде как полем быть. И вручную можно вставить не поле а через библиотеку нельзя. Там какая-то подготовка запросов и получается что ожидается поле таблицы. А оно не существует с именем, например '2017-12-4'

Comment: ставьте его вручную, это же результат обработки даты, он никаких инъекций содержать не должен.

Comment: К сожалению, дата передается от клиента, так что придется проверять её по старинке - регулярками..

Comment: `date(format, strtotime(датаКлиента));`